# MSBuildWorkspace Get Embedded Resource Files

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn

I'm trying to get out all embedded resource files from a solution using Roslyn and MSBuild Api.

```
private async Task<Document> CheckConstForLocalization(Document document, LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax localDeclaration,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    foreach (var project in document.Project.Solution.Projects)
    {
        foreach (var sourceDoc in project.AdditionalDocuments)
        {
            if (false == sourceDoc.Name.EndsWith(".cs"))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(sourceDoc.Name);
            }
        }

        foreach (var sourceDoc in project.Documents)
        {
            if (false == sourceDoc.Name.EndsWith(".cs"))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(sourceDoc.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    var newRoot = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);
    // Return document with transformed tree.
    return document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
}
```

When I modify my resource files to be AdditionFiles, I can get them through the project AdditionalDocuments.  However I would like to be able to grab these with out doing so.  The file does not appear in Documents or Additional Documents

How can I find Resx files without modifying their attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, at the moment. It isn't supported by the API. (I was researching this just yesterday.)

There's a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7772) to support it which you might like to support and subscribe to, but I don't believe there's any way of doing this at the moment.

My understanding is that Visual Studio hooks into MSBuild more tightly than Roslyn's support does at the moment. (See the [issue I raised about `<Deterministic>`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/19651) for another example.)

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to locate it's designer file, but I don't know of a way to relaibly be assured it connected to a resx

Comment: @johnny5: I suspect anything you do there may end up being brittle. Are the details in the csproj file itself? Maybe you could read that directly instead - although again, there'll be brittleness in terms of properties and conditional bits.

Comment: You should use the MSBuild APIs directly.

Comment: @SLaks how can you do it through msbuild API?

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out a way to find the designer files, I get the associated C# Document names by iterating over the csproj file and getting the embedded resources.

```
public const string LAST_GENERATED_TAG = "LastGenOutput";
public const string RESX_FILE_EXTENSION = ".resx";
public List<string> GetResourceDesignerInfo(Project project)
{
    XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(project.FilePath);
    XNamespace msbuild = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";

    var resxFiles = new List<string>();
    foreach (var resource in xmldoc.Descendants(msbuild + "EmbeddedResource"))
    {
        string includePath = resource.Attribute("Include").Value;

        var includeExtension = Path.GetExtension(includePath);
        if (0 == string.Compare(includeExtension, RESX_FILE_EXTENSION, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var outputTag = resource.Elements(msbuild +  LAST_GENERATED_TAG).FirstOrDefault();

            if (null != outputTag)
            {
                resxFiles.Add(outputTag.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    return resxFiles;
}
```